# Mirroring the Offical Magento Commerce Subversion

Tags: backup

Call me paranoid but I like having a mirror of codebases we actively develop with at work. I see that Magento Commerce allows you to checkout (via svn) a particular branch via http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/{version no}

However I want to setup a mirror of the entire repository. I also noticed that http://svn.magentocommerce.com/svn/ requires a login and guest access has been denied. Is there a way to mirror the entire repository?

As a side note I'm only looking to mirror the community edition.

Comment: Side note: there are Git equivalents on GitHub

Comment: i guess you just need 1.9?? download latest 1.9.2.2 archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Open Mirror by OpenMage on github what have all the Community Versions of magento - https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/

Comment: I'm assuming that OpenMage gets their data from the official Magento downloads?

Comment: @WilliamKnauss correct as soon as a new release is available they download it and add it to source control :)